# How do I open a reminder from Outlook popup via keyboard?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-outlook-2013

In all previous versions of Outlook, when a reminder popped up, you could open the reminder by hitting <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> on the keyboard. However, that keystroke is no longer functional in the popup, and I have found no other way to open an item using the keyboard. How do I perform this function with the keyboard, preferably in one keystroke?

To save effort, please note that this question is not in regard to how to do this with the mouse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an old question, but not answered correctly - Use the space bar to open the reminder.

Comment: It took two years, but we have a winner!

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> is the shortcut to open the format dialog. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> is used to open the selected item. What I found is that the keyboard shortcuts are almost identical for versions 2003 through 2013.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> works for me in Outlook 2010 to do as you described.

[Keyboard shortcuts for Microsoft Outlook 2013](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/keyboard-shortcuts-for-microsoft-outlook-2013-HA102606407.aspx)

Comment: That keystroke appears to be broken as well in Outlook 2013.

Comment: Do you know anyone else who has 2013 who can verify that claim? You need to verify it isn't something isolated to your system. Unfortunately, I don't have Outlook 2013 or I would check for you. I would imagine if you are right, it can be reported to Microsoft as a bug.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I can confirm it.  I 'upgraded' to Office 2013 last week.  I used Alt+O all the time to open a reminder in the reminder window in Office 2010.  Alt+O used to work because there was an Open button with the 'O' underlined as the shortcut.  The Open button no longer exists and Ctrl+O doesn't work either.

As a klunky workaround for now, I can use the context menu key on my keyboard (the key between Alt and Ctrl on the right side of the spacebar) and then choose 'Open' from the popmenu.

Microsoft removing the Open button has to be one of the dumbest usability/accessibility blunders they've made.